# Are there examples of agents that use a more modest number of parameters on Pendulum (or similar environments)?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, architecture, environment, ddpg, weights

I'm looking at some baseline implementations of RL agents on the [Pendulum](https://gym.openai.com/envs/Pendulum-v0/) environment. My guess was to use a relatively small neural net (~100 parameters).

I'm comparing my solution with some baselines, e.g. the top entry on the [Pendulum leaderboard](https://github.com/openai/gym/wiki/Leaderboard#pendulum-v0). The models for these solutions are typically **huge**, i.e. ~120k parameters. What's more, they use very large replay buffers as well, like ~1M transitions. Such model sizes seem warranted for Atari-like environments, but for something as small as the Pendulum, this seems like complete overkill to me.

Are there examples of agents that use a more modest number of parameters on Pendulum (or similar environments)?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just started inspecting the entries further down in the leaderboard list, and there are in fact more modest architectures, e.g. [this one](https://gist.github.com/heerad/1983d50c6657a55298b67e69a2ceeb44#file-ddpg-pendulum-v0-py), which uses 3 hidden layers with 8 units each.